# How to insert a boolean field in a mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I like to initially save data to a new mongodb in my Meteor App. The collection is a available an the following code works. 
But decision.visble is created as String, though I would like to have it as boolean. How do I pass this information? Is this done via the insert?

**Client**

```
  var decision = {};
  decision.visble = 'false';

  Meteor.call('addDecision',decision);
```

**Sever**

```
 'addDecision':function(decision){
    return Decision.insert(decision);
 }
```

**EDIT**

Just found a kind of answer for me:

The type seems to be take automatically. So when I leave out the quotes and pass only `false` instead of `'false'` I get a boolean type instead of a sting.

But there must be a smarter procedure. Here [is a List of BSON types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)

which seem to be used in an $type operator. So finally remains the question:

How do I correctly define the datatypes I want to store in a collection?

Comment: Please do not change the question you ask after having asked it. @saimeunt's answer makes no sense to your last question now. If you have found the answer to your question, post it (or accept one that worked), and open a new question if you have one.

Comment: For the second question: take a look at [collection2](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/collection2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assigned the `visible` field using the string syntax `"false"` so its JS type will be `String`.

You simply need to make the field into a `Boolean` using the plain `false` keyword :

```
decision.visible = false;
```

EDIT :

> How do I correctly define the datatypes I want to store in a
>   collection?

You could use something like `simple-schema` : https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema